# How to find the corresponding table with one input value in two tables of the same type in Lua

Tags: lua

i wanna output the name of table i need

table A and B like this

```
A ={ 
   name1 ={}
      };
B ={ 
   name2 ={}
     }
```

The input value is equal to one of the names, how do I determine to select the corresponding table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a map-table with name as key and table as value.

```lua
local NamedTables = {
    Name1 = Table1;
    Name2 = Table2;
    -- etc
}
```

You need to add your table to this map. The search will have constant O(1) complexity.

Comment: appreciate!!!!!

Comment: @Gipnoza if my answer helped you, accept my question as StackOverflow rules says